# Using OR Condition with facetwp facets

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters

I am using **facetwp** plugin in my site and i want to work with facets using **OR** condition as the checkbox facet type works using AND condition by default.

I am using a custom taxonomy to filter my posts and want them to filter using above condition.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this on the facet settings section with the "Behavior" parameter. More info on the [FacetWP documentation](https://facetwp.com/documentation/facets/facet-types/checkboxes/).

Comment: Yup. Found it in Behaviour parameter settings. Just changed it to **Match any** from **Match all**. Thank you.